# Cannot contact site at the specified URL There is no Web named "Website Name"

Tags: 2013, 2010, csom

I am trying to get the clientcontext of the subsite that I create

In the below code I check if the site exits and return the url if its existing

```
            var web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web, w => w.Webs);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var subWeb = (from w in web.Webs where w.Title == webTitle select w).SingleOrDefault();
            if (subWeb == null)
                return false;
            Url = subWeb.Url;
```

This works for cases where the website url is not containing special characters like **`é`**

When it has characters like that I get the below error

> Cannot contact site at the specified URL
>   https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/xxx-BeaujonImieMol�culaire.

I doubt that **`�`** part of the URL as its not the same special character

How should I handle this? How should characters like � be handled or converted to actual character?

Comment: How are you passing the `webTitle` parameter ? Looks like an issue there

Comment: I'm reading it from excel, and the parameter also contains �  instead of the actual character

Comment: hmm, fix it there. Code looks fine

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once. I solved it by copying the text into notepad and encode it to UTF-8